# Bugzilla Apache server config

Tags: apache, virtualhost, bugzilla, apache-config

I have installed Bugzilla on my dedicated server with Centos5.5.
I have already a website running on this server with Apache config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/XXX
..
</VirtualHost>
```

and I have defined a new virtual host on Apache as

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/bugzilla

   <Directory /var/www/html/bugzilla>
      AddHandler cgi-script cgi pl
      Options +Indexes +ExecCGI
      DirectoryIndex index.cgi
      AllowOverride Limit
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

However, I can't reach bugzilla anyway.. What is the right way to do that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any chance that the firewall is blocking port 8000?

Comment: How can I check/open that port ?

Comment: You can check here http://ll.51f.us/?p=217 for an example of how to modify iptables configuration.

Comment: you can check open ports with netstat -an